# В чем разница Task.Delay().Wait(); и await Task.Delay(); C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, async-await, task

погружаясь в асинхроннку WinForms не могу понять в чем разница `Task.Delay(3000).Wait();` и `await Task.Delay(3000);`
Чем будут отличаться 2 этих кода при выполнении

```
if (true)
{
    asyncFun()
}

private async void asyncFun()
{
    Task.Delay(3000).Wait();
}
```

---

```
if (true)
{
    asyncFun()
}

private async void asyncFun()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);
}
```

Comment: В том что `Wait()` блокирует вызывающий поток, а `await` - нет. Никогда не используйте `Wait()`. В случае, если вам нужна синхронная блокировка потока на время, лучше тогда используйте `Thread.Sleep()` вместо `Task.Delay().Wait()`, он дает меньше нагрузки на систему.

Comment: `Чем будут отличаться 2 этих кода при выполнении` - тем что первый "повесит" форму на 3 секнуды, а второй - нет.

Comment: @aepot Тогда почему я не могу вызвать несколько 'await Task.Delay(3000);' В одной async функции?

Comment: Можете вызвать сколько угодно раз. Как и любой другой метод. Либо я не понял, о чем вы.

Comment: можно вызвать, только выполнятся они последовательно, потому что после каждого await будет сформирован callback метод, который и будет обрабатывать следующую инструкцию await только после прохождения первой